# Selling Personal Laptop - How to Transfer Windows 10 and Office Home 2016 License to Buyer

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, license, transfer

- Windows 10 Home
- MS Office Home and Student 2016

Both were preinstalled when I purchased the laptop from HP and so I presume they are OEM license (I was not billed for it separately) and they are now linked to my Microsoft Account. Online, some are saying that OEM licenses cannot be transferred from one MS Account to another - is that true?

Worst case (if OEM license is not transferable), I was thinking of handing over my Microsoft Account too to the seller by changing the Login Email Address as described here - [How to Change the Login Email Address for Windows 10 Microsoft Accounts](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/change-login-email-address-windows-10-microsoft-accounts/). Is there any cons to this I should be aware off, or any practical reason why this isn't advisable?

Comment: It is against the Terms of Service to transfer your Microsoft Account.  Performing a Reset and choosing the option not to keep personal files is enough.  Your Office license is not linked to the machine but your Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 1):

> some are saying that OEM licenses cannot be transferred from one MS
> Account to another

I agree with this - OEM licenses stay with the computer / purchaser.

The email address you used to register the computer (Your Microsoft Account) can be traced to you.  I would not give this away as you do not know what might happen that can negatively affect you.

Presumably you have the purchase receipt for the computer. Give a copy of this to the purchaser so they may go to Microsoft Support and re-register the two licenses.

If no paperwork, consider selling the laptop without an OS and wipe it bare.  This will lower the value of the laptop.

You can also uninstall just Office and keep that license for yourself to use on a new computer. You can download and install Office with that license. You can log into your Microsoft Account and de-activate the computer you are selling.